# Is there a way to issue tokens infinitely?

Tags: smart-contract, tokens

I want to design a system  where token supply can grow infinitely.
Is it possible not to fix total supply at the token creation moment?

Comment: How to prevent stackoverflow?

Comment: So I should create UINT64_MAX supply at the beginning.

Comment: This is an old post, but I leave a comment for giving information. The maximum amount of asset is not UINT64_MAX, but `eosio::asset::max_amount` (2^62 - 1) to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 0):

No, max supply is set when the token is created and cannot be later changed.

Answer (score 0):

Using source code, you should have an update action that will modify `maximum_supply` and issue a token by symbol.

Example: https://bloks.io/account/vnpittokennn?loadContract=true&tab=Actions&account=vnpittokennn&scope=vnpittokennn&limit=100&action=update

```
void token::update(name issuer,
                   asset maximum_supply)
{
  require_auth(_self);

  auto sym = maximum_supply.symbol;
  check(sym.is_valid(), "invalid symbol name");
  check(maximum_supply.is_valid(), "invalid supply");
  check(maximum_supply.amount > 0, "max-supply must be positive");

  stats statstable(_self, sym.code().raw());
  auto existing = statstable.find(sym.code().raw());
  check(existing != statstable.end(), "token with symbol does not exist, create token before update");
  const auto &st = *existing;

  check(st.supply.amount <= maximum_supply.amount, "max-supply cannot be less than available supply");
  check(maximum_supply.symbol == st.supply.symbol, "symbol precision mismatch");

  statstable.modify(st, same_payer, [&](auto &s) {
    s.max_supply = maximum_supply;
    s.issuer = issuer;
  });
}
```